# What can be used to prevent my windows from sliding down?

Tags: windows, new-home

I have wooden windows in my home, they came with a pulley mechanism to hold them up once they are opened. However, some of the pulley's cord popped, so now when I lift the lower window open and let go it falls back shut.

Are there any thing I can buy to keep the windows open without me having to wedge them ? I was thinking maybe they sell the Pulleys independently ?

Thanks in advance.

Picture of window style:

[image]

Comment: On the older ones I have repaired in the past there was an access plate on the side of the window. Remove the plate some are simple counter balance some are spring loaded. fishing the rope up to the frame was the hardest part for me but a old wire coat hanger helped me to get it in the right place.

Comment: I see, good idea; I might try and fish for the rope, then go to the store and get more durable ones and just replace, assuming this option is my only.

Comment: Yes, the cords eventually rot out... search carefully, you will probably find an access plate to get to the weights, which are correct for your window and fairly indestructible.  You may have to pop the window out to attach new cords.  Cords and pullies are readily available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of options, repairing/replacing back to original specifications is the best option. Utilize the internet to understand how to remove the sashes and access the counterweight or spring balance parts.There are a lot of videos and depictions of how the molding is typically attached/removed, and the parting bead.

For a quick concealed fix, at low cost and available at any good hardware store, you could use a retrofit sash spring to hold up the lower sash:

[image]

Comment: I just need them to be able to stay up for an upcoming inspection, this will do the job. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

This might go against your "wedge them" restriction, but I saw these when searching for something in the past...

[image]

The are actually for sale [at this site](http://www.window-woman-ne.com/window-stik/) but of course they are easy enough to make.  A simple stick would also work, but that's pretty obvious and I'm sure you considered it.

Comment: This is very interesting, I actually never thought of it, but I am looking for something more concealed. Thanks alot.